# Elasticsearch and Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, full-text-search, hdfs, search-engine

I just start digging into Elasticsearch and Hadoop. I am a bit lost about these two concepts. I found Elasticsearch is 'always' (probably biased by my limited knowledge) talked with Hadoop ecosystem (HDFS, Spark, HBase, Hive etc). At first, I thought Elasticsearch is part of Hadoop ecosystem, but it looks like I was wrong.

If I have a task of implementing a search engine, it seems enough to only have Elasticsearch for indexing and storing the data. Then will there be any reasons to leverage Hadoop in this task? If we use both HDFS and Elasticsearch to store the data, does this mean we would have the data physically stored duplicately in two formats (one for HDFS and one for Elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch is a distribute, full-text search engine. It works on its own. If you want to use it as a search engine, you can use it standalone. There is no direct relation between Elasticsearch and hadoop. But you can use them together. If you are already using hadoop and want add searching capabilities to your data, you can index your data on elasticsearch and can query it from hadoop. There is a product for that purpose: [ES-Hadoop](https://www.elastic.co/products/hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch's strength is search - if all you want to do is implement a search engine - you can stick with that. Where the power of something like Spark and/or Hadoop comes is is when you need to do large aggregations or calculations on records or returns on the order of ~100k or more. This is where Elasticsearch will have slowage (depending on your cluster sizing and specifications). For advanced analytcs, aggregations and machine learning tasks, I would leverage Spark (for its speed) and do those jobs there, feeding the output back to Elastic to visualize it with Kibana or some other utility.